# How should I understand this sentence' quite the contrary is the case'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-construction

In this following context, should I understand the sentence ''quite the contrary is the case.'' as: ''the case is quite the contrary''?
How should I understand this sentence?

Context:

> You may not be aware that, up to this day, the real significance and
> purpose of pa†icca-samuppåda are practically unknown to Western
> scholars. By this, however, I do not mean to say that nobody in the
> West has ever written or spoken on this doctrine. No, quite the
> contrary is the case.

Source:
Fundamentals of Buddhism
Four Lectures
by Nyanatiloka Mahåthera

Comment: Yes. When we say 'XXX _is the case_' we mean '_XXX _is true, accurate, correct, etc_'

Comment: Thanks @Michael Harvey.

Comment: The opposite (of what was stated in the previous sentence) is true.